# Does a woman need to giving charity when she can not fast because of a menstrual period?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, menses, fidyah

Is it true that when a woman has her monthly period that she must give money (charity) for each day of bleeding? For example, if she bleeds for 5 days then she should give money to those in need for 5 days or give the total amount of 5 days in the first day. Is this true? Some people say it only applied to Ramadan and not the full year. Is this true? What does islam say about this?

Answer (score 1):

No! That’s not true! There is no charity linked to period in any of sharia and Fiqh!

Regarding Ramadhan, one should feed a poor person for everyday he can not fast at all! This is to compensate the missing day of fast!

So if a sister had her period then she could not make it up after Ramadhan at all due to old age, continuous illness, mental illness, pregnancy or breastfeeding, etc. then she should feed a poor person for every day she missed fasting in last Ramadhan.